# pointer referring to a garbage node

Tags: c++, pointers

I am generating a large game tree that depicts an auction scenario between two nodes (referred to as type1 and type2. The tree is generated perfectly fine till I reach the fourth level of nodes.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <queue>

    #define LEVEL 8

    using namespace std;

    class payoff_node{
        int agent_1;
        int agent_2;
    };

    class node{
        public:
            /* constructor to set payoff_ptr to NULL */
            node() { 
                payoff_ptr = NULL;
                parent = NULL; 
            }

            /* print the information about the node */
            void printNode(){
                cout << "type: " << type << "\t" << "level: " << level << "\t" << "purse: $" << purse << "\t" << "parent_bid: " << parent_bid << "\t" << "parent:" << parent->getType() << "\t" << endl;
                /*for (int i = 0; i < actions.size() ; i++){
                    cout << actions[i] << endl;
                }*/
            }

            void setType(int t){    type = t;   }

            void setLevel(int l){   level = l;  }

            void setPurse(int p){ 
                purse = p; 

                /* Depending on the purse value the action space is decided */
                for(int i = 0; i <= purse ; i++){
                    actions.push_back(new node);
                }
            }

            void setParentBid(int bid){ parent_bid = bid; }

            void setParent(node &parent_node){  parent = &parent_node;  }



            int getLevel(){ return level; }

            int getParentBid(){ return parent_bid;  }

            int getPurse(){ return purse; }

            node** getParent(){ return &parent; }

            int getType(){ return type; }


            vector<node*> actions;



        private:
            int type;
            int level;
            int purse;

            int parent_bid;
            node* parent;

            payoff_node* payoff_ptr;
    };

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        bool D = false;
        /* Make the root node and set its properties */
        node root_node;
        root_node.setType(1);
        root_node.setLevel(1);
        root_node.setPurse(4);
        root_node.setParentBid(0);

    //  root_node.printNode();  
        queue<node> myQ;
        myQ.push(root_node);

        /* BFS like creation of perfect information tree */
        while(true){
            node &ext = myQ.front();
            if(D)
                cout << "h1" << endl;

            if(ext.getLevel() == LEVEL){
                break;
            }

            if(D)
                cout << "h2" << endl;

            int type = ext.getType();

            if(D)
            cout << "h3" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < ext.actions.size() ; i++){
                node &child = *(ext.actions[i]);
            if(D)
            cout << "h4" << endl;
                //process(child);

                /* set parent */
                child.setParent(ext);
            if(D)
            cout << "h5" << endl;

                /* set type  & items won so far */
                if((ext.getLevel()) % 2 == 0){    // i.e. even numbered level, then current round has ended 
                    if(i > ext.getParentBid()){
                        child.setType(type);    
                    }
                    else{
                        int type_val = ( *(*(ext.getParent()))).getType() ;
                        child.setType( type_val );
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(type == 1){
                        child.setType(2);

                    }
                    else{
                        child.setType(1);

                    }
                }

            if(D)
            cout << "h6" << endl;
                /* set level */
                child.setLevel(ext.getLevel() + 1);
            if(D)
            cout << "h7" << endl;
                /* set purse */
                if(child.getType() == ext.getType()){
                    int val = ext.getPurse() - i;
                    if(val < 0){
                        child.setPurse(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        child.setPurse(val);
                    }
                }
                else{

                    if( *(ext.getParent()) != NULL  ){
                        int val = ( *(ext.getParent()))->getPurse()  - ext.getParentBid();
                        if(val < 0){
                            child.setPurse(0);
                        }
                        else{
                            child.setPurse( val );
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        child.setPurse(3);
                    }
                }
            if(D)
            cout << "h8" << endl;

                /* set parent bid */
                child.setParentBid(i);


            if(D)
            cout << "h9" << endl;
                /* when the child is ready with all its attributes, add it to the queue */
                myQ.push(child);
                child.printNode();
            }

            cout << endl << endl << "----Next Set of Children----" << endl;
            myQ.pop();

        }



    return 0;

    }
```

The program hangs at this line `child.setPurse( val );`I believe the value calculated by the following line

```
    int val = ( *(ext.getParent()))->getPurse()  - ext.getParentBid();
```

is wrong. Where the `*(ext.getParent())` points to some garbage node. Any help will be much appreciated as I am not being able to figure this out for over 24 hours now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue is storing objects of type `node`.  You're using pointers into the queue.  You shouldn't do that!  When you pop from the queue, which you do at the end of each pass through your main loop, you destroy your object.

Look:

```
node &ext = myQ.front();

// etc...

for(int i = 0; i < ext.actions.size() ; i++){
    node &child = *(ext.actions[i]);
    child.setParent(ext);

    // etc...

    myQ.push(child);
}

myQ.pop();  // <-- POOF!!  Every pointer to 'ext' is now invalid.
```

Every time you add to the queue, you are creating a copy of your object.  When you reference that copy, you are using the queue's internal copy.  Eventually that copy will not exist.  When set that pointer as each child's parent, you are asking for serious trouble.

The only reason this doesn't blow up sooner is because you are leaking memory by not providing a proper destructor in `node` (to clean up `actions`).  If you do implement one, you will have to also implement a copy constructor (or prevent copying by making a private, empty copy constructor).

What you really need to do is change your queue to use pointers:

```
queue<node*> myQ;
myQ.push(&root_node);
// etc...
```